# Docusaurus : How to change documents sidebar id?

Tags: docusaurus

In docusaurus, Im making custom sidebars for sidebars.js like the following :

```js
const sidebars = {
  sidebar: [
    'home',
    {
      type: 'category',
      label: 'Computer Graphics',
      link: {type: 'doc', id: 'computer-graphics'},
      items: [
        'computer-graphics/1-computer-images-part-1/computer-images-part-1',
        'computer-graphics/2-computer-images-part-2/computer-images-part-2',
        'computer-graphics/3-2d-transformation/2d-transformation',
        'computer-graphics/4-3d-transformation/3d-transformation',
      ],
    },
  ],
};

module.exports = sidebars;
```

However, this doesn't works because `'computer-graphics/1-computer-images-part-1/computer-images-part-1'` and `'computer-graphics/2-computer-images-part-2/computer-images-part-2'`
document ids do not exist according to the [ERROR] in command.

The only available ids are :

- computer-graphics/3-2d-transformation/2d-transformation
- computer-graphics/4-3d-transformation/3d-transformation
- computer-graphics/computer-images-part-1/computer-images-part-1
- computer-graphics/computer-images-part-2/computer-images-part-2

This is weird because `3-2d-transformation` and `4-3d-transformation` uses number in front of folder name, but using number in `computer-images-part-1` and `computer-images-part-2` doesn't works.

I named my folder with the following format : [number]-[foldername].
This is my folder structure :

```
computer-graphics/
├── 1-computer-images-part-1/
│   └── computer-images-part-1.md
│   
│── 2-computer-images-part-2/
│   └── computer-images-part-2.md
│
│── 3-2d-transformation/
│   └── 2d-transformation.md
│
│── 4-3d-transformation/
│   └── 3d-transformation.md
│
```

Inside md file, I specified the following front matter :

```
---
slug: computer-images-part-1
id: computer-images-part-1
title: Computer Images (Part 1)
description: Computer Images (Part 1)
---
```

The only difference for `computer-images-part-2.md` is just changing from number 1 to 2

I did some experiment :

- changing front matter's id changes the third path
- changing md file name doesn't do anything
- adding another non number character such as "-", **makes it appears in the Available document ids**. `-1-computer-images-part-1` appears while `1-computer-images-part-1` doesn't.

From my experiment, I conclude : The second path should be my folder name while the third path should be front matter's id inside the md file.